# Searchkick: Boosting future dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick, solr-boost

I'm using Searchkick in a Rails project with an ElasticSearch 6.8 server. I'm trying to boost certain documents that have a year field that's equal to this year or a year in the future.

I've tried using `boost_where` and most recently `boost_by` but neither work. `boost_by` generates a `function_score` function that errors out in ElasticSearch. Here's my most recent try.

`Model.search('value', boost_by: { year: { scale: '5y' } })`

ElasticSearch seems to dislike the calendar interval (`5y`) even though this should be valid. Here's the reason object from the error:

```
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"5y\""
          }
```

I've tried setting `origin` and `decay` along with `scale` but that doesn't seem to help anything.

Here is the query generated by Searchkick (model and field names changed due to a very specific domain model).

```
  Model Search (163.5ms)  model_development/_search {"query":{"function_score":{"functions":[{"weight":1,"gauss":{"year":{"scale":"5y"}}}],"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"multi_match":{"query":"Abreu","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"Abreu","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"Abreu","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}},{"multi_match":{"query":"Abreu","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"fields":["*.analyzed"],"type":"best_fields"}}]}}]}},"score_mode":"sum"}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false,"size":10000}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year is likely not a supported date format due to it not having an absolute representation. One day is **always** 24 hours, but one year is *sometimes* 364 days and *usually* 365 days. Rather than solve for this complexity, ES likely stops at days.

If you want, you can instead use days for your scale:

```rb
Model.search('value', boost_by: { year: { scale: '1825d' } })
```

Comment: Seems so obvious in hindsight, thank you! The cherry on top is that now that it's working it's not actually doing what I want it too haha.

Comment: Lol, what are you trying to accomplish in your query? @BrandonCordell

Comment: I was am trying to boost results that have a date field that is the current year or in the future so that dates in the past weigh less. @SyntacticFructose.

Comment: Have you considered using a decay function @BrandonCordell? A decay function will penalize older content by reducing their score